# VSTS Drop Single Artifact - Release to Azure Multiple Websites

Tags: azure, deployment, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I have a Visual Studio Solution which has multiple websites projects.

I'm currently running a build in VSTS against 1 repository which is creating a `drop.zip` artifact that has produced 3 websites segmented by their project/folder name.

Now I'd like to have 3 release definitions which publish each of the respective folders to Azure App Service.

How can this be done?

Inside of the Azure App Service Release step, I can only point to a single Zip file. I need to point to a folder inside the Zip the file, correct?

[image]

Comment: please see edit

Comment: oh, i see what you mean, i dont know if there anything you can do except for packaging them individually, sorry

Comment: how do I go about packaging them up individually? i'd be fine with that approach, but can't seem to see that either

Comment: well, its just a zip file, you could run a script to package them individually, or your could be more careful in the build pipeline with how you package zip, i'm not sure, you would need to look at the result of the build and determine a way forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by using the following MSBuild configuration:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=false /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site" /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

This generated a separate Zip file for each Web App in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a zip for each of you 3 websites. Publish the websites separately to 3 different build artifacts in the build pipeline.

In the release definition add all 3 artifacts in the artifacts section and deploy them to their respective Azure App service.

[image: Build Artifacts]

Comment: Thanks! My question at this point is how to create a Zip for each of the 3 Websites

Comment: I think you already build, zip and publish the entire solution right now. Just repeat these steps 3 times and specify the path to a different project in each bulid task.

Comment: I don't follow. I'm building at the solution level. It's just passing these parameters:/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site" /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"

Comment: Are you using a build task like '.NET Core', 'MSBuild' or 'Visual Studio Build'? They all have a field 'Path to project(s)', 'Project' or 'Solution'. Write the path to a .csproj file in this field. This will only build the specified project and not the entire solution. Afterwards publish the project you just built as an artifact.

Comment: If this doesn't help please post a new question where you can describe your new problem and how your current build pipeline works in detail.

Answer (score 0):

It does not must be a zip file. Just as the high-lighted section in your screenshot. It could be a package file or folder.
[image]

So for your scenario, you just need to configure the 3 release definition to link to the same build artifact. And then in the release definition add two tasks:

1. Extract files Task - Use this task to extract the zip file
2. Azure App Service Deploy Task - In this task, set "Package or folder" path to the extracted project folder.